# Mysql-server как минимизировать расход оперативки?

Tags: mysql, память, настройка, ram

Самый дешёвый сервер (60р в месяц) лишь бы показывать дизайнеру свёрстанные странички. Оперативки - половина гига.

Настроил по минимуму:

**ngixnx** 1 процесс от root, 1 процесс от www-data.

**php-fpm** 1 процесс от root, 1 процесс от www-data.

**mysql --daemonize** пачка процессов от mysql.

Могу я заставить mysql-server не плодить много потоков? Производительность не нужна, туда никто кроме меня и дизайнера не заходит, хватит и единственного потока.

Comment: Каждое соединение с сервером порождает свой поток исполнения. Минимизируйте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете указать в файле `mysql.cnf` параметры ограничения потоков и вообще используемой памяти.

```
max_connections=1
thread_cache_size=1
```

Количество максимальных потоков коннекта и ограничение кэша потока.

Помимо этого Вы можете установить параметры потребляемой памяти через:

```
key_buffer_size
innodb_buffer_pool_size
query_cache_size 
query_cache_limit
```

И другие.

Дополнение:
Как верно сказал Вам Akina, каждое соединение порождает поток. 
Ограничить их можно примером выше.